# Panel data with N < T heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation. Should I include country dummies?

Tags: stata, autocorrelation, heteroscedasticity, fixed-effects-model, hausman

I have panel data of $N=18$ countries with $T=72$ months. Heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation are present in the dataset. I was working in Stata with `xtreg` fixed effects with clustered countries since a `hausman` test indicated so (I was suspecting it as well). My first question since I read this [(p.11)](http://www.schmidheiny.name/teaching/panel2up.pdf) *"However, the Hausman test is only valid under homoscedasticity"*:

1. I know that heteroscedasticity is present in my data from likelihood-ratio test. Should I not take `hausman` results into account? If so, do I have any alternative?

In addition, I was advised that clusters do not work if they are very few. Since my clusters of 18 countries are way fewer than the 42 indicated in "Mostly Harmless Econometrics" by Angrist & Pischke I tried to find another way to do so.

Then reading "Microeconometrics using Stata" by Cameron & Trivedi I found the `xtpcse` command which was ideal for cases like mine with smaller $N$ and larger $T$. The command was correcting for heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation. I also used the psar1 correlation and everything seemed perfect until I started wondering whether I should include country dummies in the model. No clear answer was given to this question in fora I read. I was quite sure that there is a country effect (from `hausman` test and from intuition). So I started searching for the differences between `xtreg` and `xtpcse` by running regressions when I realised that `xtpcse` with country dummies is the same as `xtreg, fe` and `xtpcse` with no dummies is the same as `xtreg, re`. Then I couldn't understand why this `xtpcse` command is proposed for cases of $N < T$ since it gives the same results as `xtreg`. Anyone could explain this?

So I'm coming to my second and third questions:

2. Should I or should I not include country dummies with my `xtpcse` command? My main problem is that country dummies change the sign of the variable I want to investigate (positive and significant without the dummies, negative and significant with) whereas the signs and significance of control variables remain (almost) unchanged. As you understand the question whether should I include them is crucial.
3. Is `xtpcse` the answer to my problem or in the end it doesn't really help?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I also posted this question on http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/561090-panel-data-with-n-t-heteroscedasticity-and-autocorrelation-should-i-include-country-dummies
I'll post any useful answer here as well.

Comment: Cross-posted on Statalist http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/561090-panel-data-with-n-t-heteroscedasticity-and-autocorrelation-should-i-include-country-dummies Here, as well as on Statalist, explicit flagging of cross-posting is good practice.

Comment: Yes Nick thank you for your comment. I edited and added that I posted on another forum (I first posted it here so I needed some time to edit my original post and add that I posted it somewhere else)

Comment: This was a typo, I corrected it. I  meant to say that xtpcse with country dummies is the same as xtreg, fe and xtpcse with no dummies is the same as xtreg, re. Thank you for noticing.